# General Position

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What does it mean when the columns of a matrix are in general position? I do not know if this is relevant or not, but the matrix in question is under-determined.

Comment: Could you provide some context as to where you encountered this notion? Maybe a quote from a text?

Comment: I guess OP is referring to subject of 'Compressed Sensing'. See this paper `D.L. Donoho, “Compressed sensing,” IEEE. Trans. Info. Thry.,
vol. 52, no. 4, pp. 1289–1306, 2006`

Answer (score 4):

I have never heard it used quite this way, but here's what is most probably meant.
Let's say we have an $(m\times n)$-matrix $A$. Then the columns of $A$ can be considered as points in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let's call these points $p_1, \ldots, p_n$. Then by *the columns of $A$ are in general position*, what is probably meant is that the points $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ are in [general linear position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position#General_linear_position).

The points $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ are in general linear position if they are not all in the same $(n-2)$-dimensional affine subspace.

Examples:

- the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are in general position, because they are not equal;
- the points $(1,0)$, $(\frac12,\frac12)$ and $(0,1)$ are not in general position, because they are contained in the line $x+y=1$.